# Convert.ChangeType problems with passing a double

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I am using this line of code to convert strings to `int16`, `int32`, `double` and other types:

```
var convertedValue = value == null ? null : Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Can anyone explain to me why `convertedValue` is set to e.g. `205.0` when `value = "20,5"` and `targetType` is double?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's it meant to do, `,` isn't a decimal separator in the `InvariantCulture`

Comment: yeah i just figured that out too. When debugging i typed into my GUI 20.5, but when retrieving the value somewhere else the ToString() method changed this value to "20,5". Strange

Comment: Why is it strange? `ToString()` will respect the current culture. You're explicitly overriding it when you do `Convert.ChangeType`. `double`s don't have some culture that they carry around with them.

Comment: Use CurrentCulture, but not the invariant, because afaik ToString on decimal (also double of course) uses CurrentCulture

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Its a decimal separator. Like 20000 can be written in string as 20,000. Similarely when you convert 20,000 to double it will give you 20000.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in my VB.Net project. The reason of this was that compiler treated values with comma (`"20,5"`) like strings, because there is no decimal point for decimal value, therefore it convert `"20,5"` into `205` . I solved this issue by replacing comma with dot using

```
.ToString().Replace(",", ".")
```